# k-Fold Cross Validation in R - Negative Value Predictions

Tags: r

My predicted values are all negative. I would have expected 0's or 1's. Can anyone see where i am going wrong?

```
fold = 10
end = nrow(birthwt)
fold_2 = floor(end/fold)

df_i = birthwt[sample(nrow(birthwt)),] # random sort the dataframe birthwt

tester = df_i[1:fold_2,]  # remove first tenth of rows - USE PREDICT ON THIS DATA
trainer = df_i[-c(1:fold_2),]  # all other than the first tenth of rows - USE GLM ON THIS DATA

mod = glm(low~lwt,family=binomial,data=trainer)
ypred = predict(mod,data=tester) # predicted values
```

Comment: When including code, make sure your example is [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Include sample input data so we can test possible solutions. This makes it much easier to help you.

Answer (score 2):

The default for `predict.glm` is to give you the value of the link (on the scale of the linear predictors) before transformation. If you want to predict the response, use

```
ypred <- predict(mod, data=tester, type="response")
```

If may be helpful to read the `?predict.glm` help file.

Comment: Well, unless you supply data, it's impossible to know if those values are reasonable.

Comment: Apologies Mr Flick, i'm using the birthwt data file from library(MASS) and doing a 10 fold CV  to determine which of the variables predict the low variable.

Comment: Those values seem reasonable. The "low" even doesn't occur that often. If you look at the proportion of low given lwt, you see: `barplot(with(birthwt, tapply(low, cut(lwt, breaks=5), mean)))` so really in none of those groups does low occur more than 50% of the time. So regressing on lwt alone won't get you very high probabilities.

Comment: Here is my code:library(MASS)
tenfold3 = function() {
  fold = 10
  end = nrow(birthwt)
  fold_2 = floor(end/fold)  
  misclasrate=numeric()
  
  for(i in 1:10){
    
    df_i = birthwt[sample(nrow(birthwt)),] # random sort the dataframe birthwt
    
    #some code removed to allow posting
    
    misclasrate[i] = 1-sum(val_df$misclas) / nrow(val_df)
    mean_mrate = signif(mean(misclasrate),4)
    return(mean_mrate) 
  }
}